# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0, [ng] but Angular version 14.0.4 was found instead

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-cli, angular14

I did update my ionic project to Angular 14.
Tested all and everything was working when I used `ionic s`.
I wanted to test on my android device and ran `ionic cordova run android` but got the following error

```
[ng] This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0,
[ng] but Angular version 14.0.4 was found instead.
```

How can I fix this error?

#### Additional

I'm using :

- "@angular/*": "14.0.4"
- "@ionic/angular": "6.1.12"
- "@ionic/cli": "6.20.1"

Both of them should accept the angular v14...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found here a similar topic for for `Ionic cordova run ios` https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4876

For the moment, the only available fix is to
"downgrading "manually" until the `package.json`, `ionic info` and `ng version` have angular 13.3.x."